# Redirect specific url to homepage

Tags: regex, reactjs, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am building a React (frontend) with Wordpress (Backend - REST API) website. My domain is example.com which is going to have my React app (frontend) and on example.com/backend I have the Wordpress installation.

My problem is: I want to redirect example.com/backend and everything on to example.com except example.com/backend/wp-admin (so i can login). Is that do-able?

**In a sentence: Can u redirect example.com/backend but have example.com/backend/wp-admin working (not redirecting)?**

I tried lots of reggex in my .htaccess but none would do the trick.

    `RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fanismahmalat.com/backend$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.)?wp-login.php(.)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.)?wp-admin$
    RewriteRule ^(.)$ https://example.com/ [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

One way to exclude a URL is to have a rule before the "real" redirect, e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^backend/wp-admin - [L]
RewriteRule ^backend/ https://example.com [R,L]
```

The first rule will handle the wp-admin case. The second rule will catch anything else starting with `backend/`.

---

Another solution would be to exclude the specific URL from being rewritten

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend/wp-admin
RewriteRule ^backend/ https://example.com [R,L]
```

---

When the .htaccess file is in the `backend` sub-folder, the rules are almost the same, but the [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) pattern does not include the `backend` prefix

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend/wp-admin
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com [R,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^wp-admin - [L]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com [R,L]
```

Comment: So, I have 2 .htaccess files. one in the public_html folder and one in the subfolder which has the WP installed. In which one should I do that?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. I get redirection for example.com/backend but also for /backend/wp-admin i get the link for wp login page but the actual page doesn't load.

Comment: Maybe there are other rules interfering?